# inspecting types OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

I want to write a function that does different things based on the type of the input. Or in other words: How do I write code equivalent to this python code:

```
def stringOrInt(a):
     if type(a) is str:
         return "it's a string"
     elif type(a) is int:
         return "it's a int"
     else
         return "it's neither"
```

Comment: The answer is that you don't. OCaml types are not available at runtime. Do you have a concrete use case in mind?

Comment: You can't inspect types, use a variant type `type stringOrInt = String of string | Int of int` if you need that. Or a GADT type for more complex use cases where the input and output types need to match, e.g. unpack_stringOrInt should return string for `String "str"` and int for `Int 42`.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why would you have a statically unknown type ?

Answer (score 1):

Ocaml does not support that inspection of types.  Depending on what you want to do a possible workaround is to use a variant
`type StrOrInt = String of string | Int of int | Neither`

Then your function would do a pattern match on the variant

```
let str_or_int a = match a with 
| String s -> print_string "this is a string"
| Int i -> print_string "this is an int"
| Neither -> print_string "neither"
```